# How to show/hide a div when clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm using a Lightning Web Component.
On the left side there is a hyperlink (verically listed), on the right side there is `div` in a form.

The `onclick` of the link tag on the right side should be changed.

For example:

In the screenshot below, on click of the "Family Name" link, the right `div` should be shown with two fields. On click of the "Parent/Guardian" link, the first `div` should hide and the second `div` should be shown in the same place.

[image]

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={enrollmentId} object-api-name="Enrollment__c">


    <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-6">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
                    <div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
                      <ul aria-describedby="entity-header">
                        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" onclick={tabchange} aria-current="true"   >Family Name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" onclick={tabchange} >Parent/Guardian</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" onclick={tabchange} >Students</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" onclick={tabchange} >Student Programs</a>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-size_4-of-6">
          <div>
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <template for:each={familyName} for:item="field" for:index="index">
                    <div class={sectionLayout} key={field.fieldAPI}>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={field.fieldAPI} required={field.required}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div> 
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
              <template for:each={parentName} for:item="field" for:index="index">
                  <div class={sectionLayout} key={field.fieldAPI}>
                      <lightning-input-field field-name={field.fieldAPI} required={field.required}>
                      </lightning-input-field>
                  </div>
              </template>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class Enrollment_1 extends LightningElement {
@track enrollmentId;
@track family = "Show";
@track boolVisible = false;

@track familyName = [
{ fieldAPI: "Family_Name__c", required: true, fieldName: "Name" },
{ fieldAPI: "Home_Phone__c", required: true }
];

@track parentName = [
{ fieldAPI: "Family_Name__c", required: true, fieldName: "Name" },
{ fieldAPI: "Home_Phone__c", required: true }
];

tabchange(event) {
//alert(event);
//alert(event.currentTarget);
const label = event.target.label;
alert(label);
if (label === "Show") {
this.family = "Hide";
this.boolVisible = true;
}  else if  ( label === 'Hide' ) {  

this.family = 'Show';  
this.boolVisible = false;  

}  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `lightning-vertical-navigation` base component that does just that:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-vertical-navigation/example

Check out the "Vertical Navigation in Action" example for your use case.

Comment: @user3214361 I see that you've opened a new question on vertical navigation, can you validate my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<div style="min-width: 225px; border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={selectedItem} onselect={handleSelect} class="navigation">
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Recently Viewed" name="reports_recent"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Private Reports" name="reports_private"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>                    
            </lightning-vertical-navigation>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">               
            <template if:true={reportrecent}>
            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                These are the Recently Viewed!
            </div>
        </template>
         <template if:true={privatereport}>
            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                These are the Private Reports!
            </div>
        </template>


        <template if:true={pubreport}>
            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                <lightning-button name="add_student" label="Add Student" title="Add Student" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </template>


        </lightning-layout-item>

    </lightning-layout>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleVerticalNavAdvanced extends LightningElement {
selectedItem;

handleSelect(event) {
    this.selectedItem  = event.detail.name;  
}

 handleClick(event) {
this.clickedButtonLabel = event.target.label;  

}

get reportrecent() {
    return this.selectedItem === 'reports_recent';
 }

 get privatereport() {
     return this.selectedItem === 'reports_private';
 }

  get pubreport() {
     return this.selectedItem === 'reports_public';
 }
}
```